# how to use triggers(observers ) in magento for user registration

Tags: magento, triggers, observers

I need to change  customer status after registration.So when a user try to login in my site after admin approval he can access the account and same time  i want to use trigger and change the status of that customer and that update given to my Another SAP server database So here I need know what event will be triggered during customer status is changed status..?Please any one answer my question..

Answer (score 0):

Here am using Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation code

****** Code************

public function customerSaveAfter($observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

```
    $helper = Mage::helper('customeractivation');
    $storeId = $helper->getCustomerStoreId($customer);

    if (! $helper->isModuleActive($storeId)) {
        return;
    }

    $groupId = $customer->getGroupId();
    $defaultStatus = $helper->getDefaultActivationStatus($groupId, $storeId);








    try {
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            if (!$customer->getOrigData('customer_activated') && $customer->getCustomerActivated()) {
                // Send customer email only if it isn't a new account and it isn't activated by default
                if (!($customer->getCustomerActivationNewAccount() && $defaultStatus)) {
                    $helper->sendCustomerNotificationEmail($customer);

              ***  Added Code Here **********
```

Getting user details and after admin approval customer details will be send through your API to another server

```
                    $CustomerID=$customer->getId();
                    $FirstName=$customer->getFirstname();
                    $MiddleName=$customer->getMiddlename(); 
                    $LastName=$customer->getLastname();
                    $Gender=$customer->getGender();
                    $EmailID=$customer->getEmail();
                    $WebSite=$customer->getWebsiteId();
                    $GroupID=$customer->getGroupId(); 
                    $DOB=$customer->getDob();
                    $TaxVat=$customer->getTaxvat();
                    $date= date("Ymd", strtotime($DOB));
                    $url = "http://server/WebSAPApi/Service1.asmx/CreateCustomer?CustomerID=$CustomerID&FirstName=$FirstName&MiddleName=$MiddleName&LastName=$LastName&Gender=$Gender&EmailID=$EmailID&WebSite=$WebSite&GroupID=$GroupID&DOB=$date&TaxVat=$TaxVat";
                   function httpGet($url)
                    {
                        $ch = curl_init();  

                        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);


                        $output=curl_exec($ch);

                        curl_close($ch);
                        return $output;
                    }                   

                    $msg = httpGet($url);
                    Mage::log($url.$msg, null, 'mylog.log', true);**
```

****** End of the Added code**********

```
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($customer->getCustomerActivationNewAccount()) {









                // Only notify the admin if the default is deactivated or the "always notify" flag is configured
                $alwaysNotify = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ALWAYS_NOTIFY_ADMIN, $storeId,$d);
                if (!$defaultStatus || $alwaysNotify) {
                    $helper->sendAdminNotificationEmail($customer);
                }




            }
            $customer->setCustomerActivationNewAccount(false);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```